# calling a method on client side on update in database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, notifications

I have a database in my sql and I have multiple clients using that database.
whenever a column in the database is updated I want to call the corresponding java method on the client side. Basically this is the message system, when user get new message I want to give him a notification. Is this the right way to do it? If yes how do I implement it. If not what would be the right way to do it?

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are messaging frameworks for such reason for example :

- Jabber
- UDP multicast (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html)
- JMS (http://activemq.apache.org/)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not the right way to do it. To send messages, use message-oriented middleware (MOM), using JMS. There are free JMS implementations available (like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), for example).

Answer (score 2):

You might find interesting the following blog post and thread: http://www.unlimitednovelty.com/2009/04/twitter-blaming-ruby-for-their-mistakes.html

The blog was written when Twitter has changed its messaging system platform from Ruby to Scala. It generated an ineteresting flame about messaging systems between experts...